# Java JFrame will not display

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, swing, authentication

I am trying to code for an authentication server login project and my JFrame will not display. It displayed once, but when I attempted to alter the code, it would not display. The code that ran previously was:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Login{
    Connection con;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;

    JFrame LoginUI1 = new JFrame("User Login");
    JLabel l = new JLabel("Username:");
    JLabel ll = new JLabel("Password:");
    JTextField t2 = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);
    JButton b = new JButton("Login");

    public Login(){
        connect();
        frame();

    }
    public void connect(){

        try
        {
       String driver = "sun.dbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"; 
       Class.forName(driver);

       String db = "jdbc:odbc:library";
       con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
               st = con.createStatement();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    public void frame()
    {
        LoginUI1.setSize(600,400);
        LoginUI1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        LoginUI1.setVisible(true);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(l);
        p.add(t2);
        p.add(ll);
        p.add(t1);
        p.add(b);

        LoginUI1.add(p);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String user = t2.getText().trim();
                String pass = t1.getText().trim();

                String sql = "select user,pass from login where user = '"+user+"'and pass = '"+pass+"'";
                try {
                    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

                int count = 0;
                try {
                    while(rs.next()){
                        count = count +1;
                    }
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

                if (count ==1)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User found, access granted!");
                }
                else if(count > 1)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicate user found, no access!");
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User not found!");
                }
                }


            });
        }
}

        /*
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
    }
*/
```

Comment: What did you put in your `main` method?

Comment: Are you getting any kind of exception thrown anywhere?

Comment: I apparently did not use a main method. I am brand new to coding so I followed a tutorial to complete a class assignment.

Comment: Pretty sure you've got a `main` method somewhere!

Comment: There is no exception and there are no compilation errors. The code worked previously exactly as it is above, but suddenly stopped displaying the frame.

Comment: How do you actually run this program?  Do you know what arguments are being passed on the java command line?

Comment: I am using NetBeans for this. I'm really a new person to this type of coding and was unable to drop this class due to the accelerated nature of the curriculum so I am just absolutely lost.

Comment: OK, so which class are you telling NetBeans to run?

Answer (score 2):

Don't make the frame visible until you have added all the components first.   Specifically move this line to the end of the frame mehthod:

```
LoginUI1.setVisible(true);
```

Unrelated to your problem:

- Don't name variable names with uppercase letters as this makes it look like a class name.  (Example: `LoginUI1` )

Comment: Why do you suggest not do add component directly to the frame? The API was changed in JDK5 to allow you do to this. The add is forwarded to the content pane.

Comment: I followed your advice, yet the frame still does not display (I changed the variable name as well). I'm not sure how to proceed from this point.

Comment: @user3105217 `catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }` this is your problem, second you shouldn't open your connection in constructor, you should have to do it in the actionListener and when you finish statement release resources.

Comment: @nachokk I seriously doubt whether that's the problem.  If an exception were thrown there, then there'd be a null pointer exception thrown in the `frame()` method.  The OP claims that this doesn't happen.

Comment: @DavidWallace that's certainly true!

Answer (score 0):

You did not add any main method to run this class. After  `public class Login{` add `public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new Login();
    }`

This should run your code. For details description about main method go to **The main Method** part of following link:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/

Thanks.